# django: add form field to generated form from another table

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I have this table Products:

size
color
etc

and another table Pictures:
product_id
picture

and I have generated form from Products table, but I also need there field for adding a picture to that product. Is it possible to add a field to the product generated form for a  picture?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can include multiple forms in the same `<form>` tag, by using the [prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) argument.

Exclude the product field from the picture model form. In the view, check if both forms are valid. If both forms are valid, save both forms, but use `commit=False` for the picture form so that you can manually set the product.

Putting that all together, your forms and view should look something like this:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product

class PictureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        exclude = ('product',)

def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        product_form = ProductForm(prefix="product", data=request.POST)
        picture_form = PictureForm(prefix="picture", data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if product_form.is_valid() and picture_form.is_valid():
            product = product_form.save()
            picture = picture_form.save(commit=False)
            picture.product=product
            picture.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/success_url/")
    else:
        product_form = ProductForm(prefix="product")
        picture_form = PictureForm(prefix="picture")
    return render(request, "my_template.html", {'product_form':product_form, 
                                   'picture_form': picture_form,
                                   })
```

Your template should look something like this:

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      {{ product_form }}
      {{ picture_form }}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: nitpick: the first parameter of `render()` is `request`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. You would have to be careful with your template and views.

Can you please share your code... view, django models and template. Are you using model forms? Why are you keeping them as separate models (tables)?

My suggestion is if you don't need to keep the models separate, edit the Product model to include Pictures. Then your form will suit your needs nicely.

Hope this helps. If not, share code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First I had picture in product table, but then I realized I'll need more than one picture to one product so I made special table for pictures. The code from Alasdair did the job.