# Form not passing is_valid() check when trying to use form data from another form

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I have two forms in two separate models: Trainer and User.

The Trainer form has one field called price_for_trainer that I need to pull into the User form. It's getting pulled in with the default value of 0 but I need the price for the trainer, like $5000, which would have been entered by the trainer.

I'm using the prefix keyword (see code below) as described in this example: [django: add form field to generated form from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165046/django-add-form-field-to-generated-form-from-another-table)

But when I debug my code `trainer_form.is_valid()` inside of `if request.method == "POST":` returns False, so my code block doesn't get executed.

Also, when debugging I'm printing the form errors for Trainer and they say `field is required`.

I should also mention that I'm using forms.ModelForms for both my Trainer and User.

Here's what I've tried.

- I've tried using the prefix keyword in my User view (see code below) which pulls in the price_for_trainer field from the Trainer form but sets the field to the default value of 0

Here's my code:

**User views.py**

```
def user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, prefix="user")
        trainer_form = TrainerForm(request.POST, prefix="trainer")

        if user_form.is_valid() and trainer_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            trainer = trainer_form.save(commit=False)
            trainer.user=user
            trainer.save()
            return redirect('/success_page')
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(prefix="user")
        trainer_form = TrainerForm(prefix="trainer")
    
    return render(request, "register/user_form.html", {'user_form':user_form, 'trainer_form':trainer_form} )
```

**user_form.html**

```
<form>
      <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
        {{ user_form.customer_name|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row" style="display: none">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
        {{ trainer_form.price_for_trainer | as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Submit Buyer</button>
</form>
```

So, how would I get the form data from my Trainer form to populate in my User form? I think if I can get `trainer_form.is_valid()` to pass I can do something like `trainer_form.cleandata['price_for_trainer']` to grab that data and populate my User form, but am not sure? Any step in the right direction would be great.

Comment: is the user going to be able to change the price? if not, it doesn't need to be an input field in the user creation form, does it? also, if the trainer object already exists and has their price field already set to a value, there's no need to grab from the trainer's **form**, just grab the price field value from the existing Trainer object. See what I mean? trying to merge forms seems, to me, to be overcomplicating your situation; you want a field from a Trainer, price, not an input field from a Trainer form.

Comment: Hi @m.arthur thank you for your response. The user will not be able to change the price, you are correct. Ok, I think I understand what you mean. So, I don't need to grab the trainer's form I can just tap into the ORM and grab the Trainer object for a particular trainer? Also, do you have any recommendations on the UI as to how a user would select a trainer? For example, there are thousands of trainers and if I had a drop down it would take forever for a user to find one.

Comment: that's an interesting problem, for sure. does the user know which trainer they are looking for? if so, you'll want to look into 'autocomplete' for an input field, which requires using jQuery usually. with this approach, as the user types a name, results will appear and get filtered based on the currently typed input. That's the only way I can think to narrow 'thousands' quickly down to fewer options, but it only works if the user knows what they are looking for in advance. Otherwise, you'll need to design logic that narrows the possible results for the user, and display just those.